# Why are there left/right gaps when I add an image to my navigationBar?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, navbar, navigationbar

```
UIImageView *navBarImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:navBarImage];
[navBarImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
self.navigationItem.titleView = navBarImageView;
[navBarImageView release];
```

I am trying to add an image to my navigationBar, but when I used the code as listed above, it places the image into the navigationBar but leaves a grey gap to the left and right of the image. The image was created at 320x44, I'm not sure why it is resizing it despite the fact that I am setting the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's... probably not how you want to do that—it's not what the `titleView` is for. The usual way to do a custom navigation-bar background is to create a category on `UINavigationBar`, like so:

```
 @implementation UINavigationBar(MyCustomBackground)
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)r
 {
      [[UIImage imageNamed:@"my-navigation-background.png"] drawInRect:self.bounds];
 }
 @end
```

Throw that in a .m file in your project and you should see all of your navigation bars use "my-navigation-background.png" as their background.

Comment: Well, I don't really want it to be for all navigation bars. I have a different navigation bar for the child screens. Can I specify it per screen?

Comment: Sure. Set the bars' `tag` property to a unique value for each different image you want to use, then check `self.tag` in the category's `-drawRect:` and draw the appropriate image.

Comment: It's working. Only problem is when I go back to the first screen, it seems to be keeping the tag from the child screen and showing the child screen navBar.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably only getting set when you create the child controller. The navigation bar persists from view to view, after all. You'll probably have better results setting the tag in `-viewWillAppear:`—from both controllers—and then calling `-setNeedsDisplay` on the bar.

Comment: I'm calling [self.navigationController.navigationBar setNeedsDisplay]; but nothing is happening.

Comment: I got it - I was calling viewDidAppear incorrectly, did not have the :(BOOL)animated

Thank You